# Why WP AJAX always return 0?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

Tried to get answer, but returns 0.
JS in the head:

```
q = new XMLHttpRequest();
q.open('POST', ajaxUrl);
q.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (q.readyState === 4) {
        console.log(q.response);
    }
};

var data = {
    'action': 'check_email'
};
q.send(JSON.stringify(data));
```

ajaxUrl links to admin_url('admin-ajax.php');
Code in the `function.php`:

```
function check_email() {
    echo 'true or false';
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_check_email', 'check_email');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_check_email', 'check_email');
```

Comment: Are you sure wp ajax accepts a json body? from what I've seen its usually in a application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data POST body

Comment: I saw it in the example from internet, `q.send('action=check_email');` returns zero too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a json request is valid, set the content-type to json

```
q.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

if it isn't send  `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` instead

```
q.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
...
q.send('action=check_email');
```

Comment: Hi @rekzi, if it works, please click on the upvote icon next to the answer to show your gratitude towards Musa :)

Answer (score 0):

`q.responseText` is what you're looking for.